# Can use .jCarouselLite one name use many div?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

```
$("#gal-row").jCarouselLite({
        vertical: false,
        hoverPause:false,
        visible: 5,
        auto:null,
        speed:1000,
        btnPrev:"#btn-next",
        btnNext:"#btn-prev",
        scroll: 5,
        circular:false
    });
```

I want use code.

Use for

```
    <div id="gal-row" style="height:105px;">
    <ul class="gallery-data slider">
    <li><img src="images/gallery-1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/gallery-2.png" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div  id="gal-row" style="height:105px;">
    <ul class="gallery-data slider">
    <li><img src="images/gallery-3.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/gallery-4.png" /></li>                              
    </ul>
   </div>
```

I want use jCarouselLite  on function is "#gal-row".
But jCarouselLite use one div it use div first and div second not use jCarouselLite.
You can help.

Answer (score 0):

your html is wrong , it shouldn't have duplicate ids

use class names instead.

```
<div id="gal-row" style="height:105px;">
    <ul class="gallery-data slider">
    <li><img src="images/gallery-1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/gallery-2.png" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div  id="gal-row" style="height:105px;">
    <ul class="gallery-data slider">
    <li><img src="images/gallery-3.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/gallery-4.png" /></li>                              
    </ul>
   </div>
```

change to class

```
<div class="gal-row" style="height:105px;">
    <ul class="gallery-data slider">
    <li><img src="images/gallery-1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/gallery-2.png" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div  class="gal-row" style="height:105px;">
    <ul class="gallery-data slider">
    <li><img src="images/gallery-3.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/gallery-4.png" /></li>                              
    </ul>
   </div>
```